# Inserting different views in Angular using the ng-view Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, nested-views

Can anyone help me with this view issue that I have. This is a hypothetical example so there is no code to see.

So say I have a site simple site with three routes

```
/signin 
/users 
/users/:id
```

I hit the sign-in route `(/signin)` and the sign-in view is inserted into `<ng-view>` in the `index.html`. The sign-in view is a simple form with username and password.

After a successful sign-in I arrive at the user list view `(/users)`, which contains say a header, footer, left-side-nav and the user list as the main content in the middle.

I then click on a user in the list and I’m taken to the user detail page `(/users/:id)`. The problem I have now is i only want to update the main content. I dont want to keep inserting the header, footer and left-nav into the view. So to get around that I could do this in my index.html

```
<header/>
<left-nav/>
<div ng-view></div>
<footer/>
```

Now when I change routes only the main content changes but the issue I have now is if I return to the signin screen it now contains a header, footer and nav that I dont want.

This ideally what I want.

- Go to sign-in page.
- Sign-in view gets inserted.
- Successful sign-in.
- User list view gets inserted. Contains header, footer, nav and main
  content containing user list.
- Click on user in list.
- User detail page is displayed in main content. Header, footer and nav
  remain static.

How do I make this work without some hooky fix?

Comment: As an addition, I know I can just hide the the other elements, i.e hide the header, footer ect, when I'm in the sign-in screen but that doesn't feel like the right thing to do. A colleague tells me that's the way you do things in Angular.

Comment: Hiding elements could lead to a code bloated with conditionals. See my example of nested views at jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is basically a nested views and states. So that all routes under `/parent` like `/parent/:id` have the same layout. As of now angular ngRoute doesn't support nested ng-views. There are two ways of solving this

1. Use the ng-include's and a separate service to handle the routing logic  i.e. when to use ng-include to get the layout (header, footer, menu) for this route and of what type.
2. Use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#nested-states--views) which supports nested routing out of the box and will likely be incorporated into the angular-core sooner or later.

Toggling visibility of the elements according to the current route is a fast way to a messed code and a lot of nested conditional statements if you are going to have more than two different layouts.

Hope this example helps [JsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/uSABApi/35/edit?html,js,output). Feel free to ask additional questions regarding the nested views.

Comment: Is this a standard way for app development in the Angular community, to use the ui-router and nested states?

Comment: I am not sure about the whole community but I do use them in my two projects and ui-router seems to be a good tool with a lot of features. Of course that is an additional code for users to download but it is worth it. I first tried to use ng-hide/ng-if/ng-switch to hide/show the elements depending on the current route. Then I moved to ng-include's and a logic of what templates to include for a given route. Now I'm using the ui-router and it handles all the issues.